# detect email view counter using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, email

I'm creating a newsletter dynamically in my ASP.NET web app. I've made an ASP.NET page which is sent my users via email, I need to know how many times this email is viewed, what are my options? I have another page which acts as an archive for my newsletters, so I should find a way that each time my email is viewed, `"numview"` column in my newsletter table is increased by one, is it possible? are there any ready made tools or I should make one using code? it is easy to make one but my page is going to be viewed as an EMAIL, so I think I cannot write SQL commands, how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be very easy to add tracking to normal email. but if you are loading some external webpage(of yours), inside the email (via an iframe or as an images source or so), you may try any of the following.

You can try incorporating some analytics code inside your page. So everytime when someone visits the page,the visits will be tracked. You will get a clear picture from the dashboard of the analytics provider. There are lot of providers but i think google analytics is the winner. It is free as well.

If you want to implement your own, you can have a one table which stores the pageid/url, users' IP Address, date, browser etc.. and add a record to this table on the page load event of your page.

Comment: well if it was a page viewed in browser, it would be very easy, but my page is viewed in EMAIL, I create an ASP.NET page which is finally sent to email as an HTML document, so I think I cannot run any server side code inside my email

Comment: you can sent the HTML email which has an image tag where the source is your external webpage where you have the tracking added.

Comment: thanks, but can I use as ASPX page for my image tag? is it possible?

Comment: Keep in mind that this technique will never be 100% accurate. Most email client readers/web clients will prohibit loading external images from unknown/untrusted sources by default. The user has to actively download the images in order for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

> I've made an ASP.NET page which is sent my users via email

I had a little trouble understanding this. If it's an ASP.NET page, then how can you send it to users?

Forgetting about ASP.NET for a minute, you can just send an HTML email. One trick is to have the email reference an image on your server. You could then write ASP.NET code to intercept that server request and count the number of times that happens.

However, this is not reliable because most email readers will not display images unless the user indicates images should be loaded for an email because spammers have used this technique too many times.

So, to the extend I understand the question, I do not believe there is a reliable way to accomplish this.

Comment: well I mean my ASP.NET page is sent to my users in its HTML format, I override my page render function, and then send the whole HTML to my users, but in this way I cannot run server side code when my users view email, because my email is an static HTML

Comment: Correct. If you are using ASP.NET to produce the HTML, there is no interaction then with that HTML.